# iOS App got rejected due to Metadata. What should be done?

Tags: ios

**The response from Apple is:**

We found that your app is not appropriate for the World storefront because it is a custom app designed specifically for EON Group of Industries, whose users are in Bangladesh.

At this time, Bangladesh is not part of the Volume Purchase Program.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to set the storefront to Bangladesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple have determined that your app really should be a B2B app rather than an App Store app since it is only targeted at employees/partners of a specific company rather than being generally useful.

Normally you would make such an app available as a B2B app that the company would purchase using the Volume Purchase Program (VPP).  Since VPP is not available in Bangladesh, they need you to limit the available regions for your app in App Store Connect to Bangladesh only rather than all regions.

*However*, Bangladesh doesn't appear to be a territory in App Store connect, so you should respond to Apple and ask which territory you should select for that region.